# Unable to create RDS instance even though subnets are in different Availability Zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform code is here:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "tf-aws-rds-1" {
  cluster_identifier      = "aurora-cluster-1"
  engine                  = "aurora-mysql"
  engine_version          = "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.03.2"
  availability_zones      = ["us-east-1a","us-east-1b","us-east-1c"]
  database_name           = "cupday"
  master_username         = "administrator"
  master_password         = var.password
  backup_retention_period = 5
  preferred_backup_window = "07:00-09:00"
  storage_encrypted       = true
  kms_key_id              = data.aws_kms_key.rds_key.arn
}
```

However, when I do run terraform apply, I get the error message below:

```
aws_rds_cluster.tf-aws-rds-1: Creating...

Error: error creating RDS cluster: InvalidVPCNetworkStateFault: DB Subnet Group doesn't meet availability zone coverage requirement. Please add subnets to cover at least 2 availability zones. Current coverage: 0
        status code: 400, request id: bc05fb5f-311c-4d15-821a-8b97fc27ab5b
```

However, I do have subnets in multiple AZ, screenshot below:

[image]

Any idea what is the issue and how do I solve it?
P.S: Subnet created as like below

```
resource "aws_subnet" "tf-aws-sn" {
  count             = var.subnet_count
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.tf-aws-vn.id
  cidr_block        = data.template_file.public_cidrsubnet[count.index].rendered
  availability_zone = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, var.subnet_count)[count.index]
  tags              = local.common_tags
}
```

Availability Zones I get as like below:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see in your code reference to [aws_db_subnet_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_subnet_group), so I guess a default subnet group used does not meet this constrain. You can create your own `aws_db_subnet_group`:

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "db_subnets" {
  name       = "main"
  subnet_ids = aws_subnet.tf-aws-sn[*].id

  tags = {
    Name = "My DB subnet group"
  }
}
```

And then use it (no need for `availability_zones` in this case)

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "tf-aws-rds-1" {
  cluster_identifier      = "aurora-cluster-1"
  engine                  = "aurora-mysql"
  engine_version          = "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.03.2"

  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.db_subnets.name

  database_name           = "cupday"
  master_username         = "administrator"
  master_password         = var.password
  backup_retention_period = 5
  preferred_backup_window = "07:00-09:00"
  storage_encrypted       = true
  kms_key_id              = data.aws_kms_key.rds_key.arn
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Marcin, I have added the code to create aws subnet.

Comment: @learner So is it working, or there is some new issue?

Comment: It will not work as I am creating subnets with the code I updated in question, perhaps the answer would change as well?

Comment: @learner I updated the answer. You can use `aws_subnet.tf-aws-sn[*].id` to get your ids.